# Can't use latin characters correctly when creating new files from within Java. Filenames get weird characters instead of the correct ones

Tags: java, file-io, character-encoding, save, filesystems

Currently saving an int[] from hashmap in a file with the name of the key to the int[]. This exact key must be reachable from another program. Hence I can't switch name of the files to english only chars. But even though I use ISO_8859_1 as the charset for the filenames the files get all messed up in the file tree. The english letters are correct but not the special ones.

```
        /**
        * Save array to file
        */
        public void saveStatus(){
            try {
                for(String currentKey : hmap.keySet()) {
                    byte[] currentKeyByteArray = currentKey.getBytes();
                    String bytesString = new String(currentKeyByteArray, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                    String fileLocation = "/var/tmp/" + bytesString + ".dat";
                    FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
                    out.writeObject(hmap.get(currentKey));
                    out.close();
                    saveFile.close();
                    System.out.println("Saved file at " + fileLocation);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Could it have to do with how linux is encoding characters or is more likely to do with the Java code?

**EDIT**

I think the problem lies with the OS. Because when looking at text files with cat for example the problem is the same. However vim is able to decode the letters correctly. In that case I would have to perhaps change the language settings from the terminal?

Comment: You should not try to convert bytes in strings to different character sets. Inside a string, the encoding is, and should only be, UTF-16. `getBytes()` gets bytes in your current JVM's default charset. `new String(...,CharSet)` Creates a string from bytes assuming that they are in the given charset. This is plainly wrong, because you extracted them as your current charset.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to modify the program reading these files? I.e. can you encode the key in the filename (base64, ...) to avoid the problem that the valid characters of filenames depend highly on the filesystem.

Comment: @RealSkeptic should I pass any encoding parameters what so ever?

Comment: You shouldn't try to change the content of strings using bytes. The issue is when Java creates the file name, and this may be filesystem dependent, or a problem in your console, or the wrong setting in one of the JVM encoding flags. Java does not give you an option to set the encoding in which file names are written.

Comment: @sruetti Well I save the files as text files in the filesystem. And then read them with the help of FileReader in java. I'm unsure if it's possible to read the filename in the way you propose though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the charset in the `getBytes` function as well.

```
currentKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Also, why are you using `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1`? To accept a wider range of characters, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the bytes should not be extracted or changed at all.

Comment: @Chinmay jain Will UTF_8 include everything in ISO_8859_1?

Comment: Yes, It will include everything in ISO_8859_1.

Answer (score 1):

The valid characters of a filename or path vary depending on the file system used. While it **should** be possible to just use a java string as filename (as long as it does not contain characters invalid in the given file system), there might be interoperability issues and bugs.

In other words, leave out all Charset-magic as @RealSkeptic recommends and it **should** work. But changing the environment might result in unexpected behavior.

Depending on your requirements, you might therefore want to encode the key to make sure it only uses a reduced character set. One variant of [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) might work (assuming your file system is case sensitive!). You might even find a library (Apache Commons?) offering a function to reduce a string to characters safe for use in a file name.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your suggestions. I've realized it has probably to do with the file system.